# Unsetting an environment variable vs. setting it to zero

Tags: bash

Is it customary to be able to disable certain functionality in a shell script by explicitly setting a variable to `0` instead of unsetting it? What would be the more canonical approach?

The reason I am asking is that unsetting a variable `X` allows syntax like `${X:-foo}`, where `foo` is returned in case `X` is not set. Setting `X` to `0` explicitly would still cause `foo` to be evaluated where that might not be intended.

Comment: There is no standard on this. Use whatever you find most useful for your application.

Comment: Setting X=0 would not cause foo to be evaluated. It is not a boolean: the test is 'unset or null'. Even a single blank is non-null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always use `unset`.

The various forms of variable expansion allow you to see if it is set or not.

```
echo ${X:- X is set and not empty}
echo ${X- X is set, maybe empty}
```

Comment: Those would only make sense if you replaced `:-` with `:+` and `-` with `+` (and quoted the expansions). Or changed it to `printf '%s\n' "${X:-X is empty or unset}"` and `printf '%s\n' "${X-X is unset}"`

Answer (score 1):

Subtler than I remembered. I never used the := version before. Evaluated left to right, and assignments are effective immediately.

This also might be an interesting purpose for the `:` built-in "Do nothing" command.

```
Paul--) unset X
Paul--) printf '%s\n' "${#X}" "${X:-foo}" \
>                     "${#X}" "${X:=foo}" \
>                     "${#X}" "${X:-why}"
0
foo
0
foo
3
foo
Paul--)
```